# How can I DbInizializer in Program in Net6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

i'm new in .net , i was following a course and i had little issue , that i can't initiliaze my Db,
I have some data that most be put in first when program launch , and i hade this essue

**IDbInitializer.cs**

```
public interface IDbInitializer
{
    public void Initialize();
}
```

**DbInitializer.cs**

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public void Initialize()
   {
     ............
   }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();

app.UseAuthorization();
dbInitialize.Initialize();<------ How can i call her here ?,
 because i keep getting error "Use of unassigned local variable 'dbInitializer'"
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 
app.Run();
```

And Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app.Services.GetService<IDbInitializer>().Initialize();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you may refer to this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-seed-initializer):

Set your `Initialize` as a static method and then it can be called like what the tutorial mentioned in your `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MvcMovie.Data;
using MvcMovie.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MvcMovieContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext")));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    SeedData.Initialize(services);
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "default",
   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your `program.cs` file

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDBInitializer, DbInitializer>();

var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDBInitializer>();
service.Initialize();
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: `IDBInitializer` should be replaced by `IDbInitializer` in the third line.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 6, the below settings worked for me.

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
 {
     var services = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitilizer>;
     services.Invoke().Initialize();
 }
```

[image: DBInitilizer]

Answer (score -1):

IDbInitializer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MWS.Data
{
    public interface IDbInitializer
    {
        void Initialize();
    }
}
```

DbInitializer.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MWS.Models;
using MWS.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MWS.Data;

namespace MWS.Data
{
    public class DbInitializer : IDbInitializer
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public DbInitializer(ApplicationDbContext db, 
                            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, 
                            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        public async void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                if(_db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count()>0)
                {
                    _db.Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

            if (_db.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == SD.AdminEndUser)) return;

            _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.AdminEndUser)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.CustomerEndUser)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            _userManager.CreateAsync(new MdlApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "admin@mws.ir",
                Email = "admin@mws.ir",
                LastName = "MWS",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumber = "+9898989898"
            }, "Uk123!@#").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(_db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == "admin@mws.ir").GetAwaiter().GetResult(), SD.AdminEndUser).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
...
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();
...

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbInitializer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();
    dbInitializer.Initialize();
}
```

SD.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MWS.Utilities
{
    public static class SD
    {
        public const string AdminEndUser = "Administrator";
        public const string CustomerEndUser = "Customer";
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How does all this code answer the question? Which parts are relevant and how are they different from previous answers?

Comment: Never mind the concurrency bug. Is this a ChatGPT answer? I see two other answers without explanations and a lot of code in the past month, to questions that have been answered already. [ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) because it results in bad answers. Removing the blurb doesn't fix the bad code